# How to send SMS from jquery/java Script where number is stored in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If user modify any values after submission, i just wanted send SMS to user about what changes has been made.

I known `<a href="sms:444?body=hello"></a>`

but how to add this in jquery or anything else is possible??

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no way to do this purely with javascript. At a bare minimum you will need to get a sever side technology involved and probably a 3rd party provider to handle the sending of the SMS.http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-send-text-messages-with-php--net-17693

Comment: @JonP so its possible using angularjs ya jquerymobile??

Comment: Angular maybe, jquerymobile unlikely as it is primarily concerned with the user interface.